# How to implement a Linq NullCheck Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm having a hard time trying to implement a nullcheck (isNull, isNotNull) expression using linq.
Here is part of my code:

```
//create a blog collection
var blogsCollection = new List<Blog>();
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
{
    var b = new Blog()
    {
        BlogId = i,
        Url = $"http://{i}.blog.com",
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-i),
    };
    blogsCollection.Add(b);
}

ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Blog), "item");
Expression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "BlogId");
Expression targetExpression = Expression.Constant(null, propertyExpression.Type);
Expression exp = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, targetExpression);
var filter=Expression.Lambda<Func<Blog, bool>>(exp, parameterExpression).Compile();
var blogs = (List<Blog>)blogsCollection.Where(filter);
```

This code throws an exception:
**Argument types do not match**

If I change the targetExpression to (without the type conversion):
Expression targetExpression = Expression.Constant(null);

Then it throws a different exception:
**System.InvalidOperationException : The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int32' and 'System.Object'**

Any Ideas about how to have a null check in Linq? I've checked here on SO, but none of them seems to work.

Comment: It looks like `BlogId` is an `int`? How come you're trying to test it for null? ints can't be null. Trying to create a constant `null` of type `int` will of course fail. If you change `"BlogId"` to `"Url"`, [everything is fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xA7eQs) (after adding the necessary `.ToList()`)

Comment: Also `blogsCollection.Where(filter).ToList()` not  `(List<Blog>)blogsCollection.Where(filter)`

Comment: The idea is to convert this to a EF database query. That's why the nullcheck it's required.
The code comes from my test method, but in the ef version, the error it's the same

Comment: The error comes from `Expression.Contant(null, typeof(int))` -- that's simply a nonsensicle thing to ask for. If the database column could be null, then presumably `BlogId` in the model is an `int?`, not an `int`. If this is the case, [everything is fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lqIkJc)

Comment: You are right! I need to get some sleep... Thank you

Comment: If `BlogId` can be null, declare it as `Nullable<int>` which is the same as `int?`. Then you can do this test. If it cannot be null, then declare it as `int` and the corresponding table column must be declared as `NOT NULL` and the test is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Id` is of type `System.Int32` which is a value type, so it is always not null (i.e. `BlogId == null` is always false). If you want to implement a generic filter which supports every possible input you can do something like that:

```
if (propertyExpression.Type.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyExpression.Type) == null)
{
    filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Blog, bool>>(Expression.Constant(false), parameterExpression).Compile();
}
else
{
    // your current code
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks

Comment: @pablor21 was glad to help!